# Everything in UIView randomly become nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to change an image shown in `UIImageView` however when the function "`loadMyImage`" is called (which is the function where I'll change the image.) Everything in the `ViewController` becomes nil.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHqHL.png)

This is the code just before I call the `loadMyImage` function.

```
let playbackPoint = defaults.float(forKey: "pbpoint")
if eachTime > Double(playbackPoint) {
   let name = imageList[timeList.index(of: eachTime)!]
   ViewController().loadMyImage(name: name)
}
```

I put a break point at this line

```
let name = imageList[timeList.index(of: eachTime)!]
```

and everything is still there
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQYK4.png)

And here's the code of `loadMyImage`

```
func loadMyImage(name: String) {
        let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(name)
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            let myImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            print(self.myImgView)
            self.myImgView.image = myImage
        } catch {
            print("Error loading image : \(error)")
        }
    }
```

As soon as the first line runs. Everything that has anything to do with UI becomes nil. I also tried printing it and it printed out "None".

I've tried cleaning the project but it still does not work.

Comment: `ViewController().loadMyImage(name: name)` is dead code. It just initializes a controller and then it's gone since there is no reference to it.

Comment: You must have a reference of ViewController(), i.e let object = ViewController() then call like object.loadMyImage(name: name)

Comment: Where is `loadMyImage` located?

Comment: @vivekDas this changes nothing, you still have a brand new local variable instead of actually displayed view controller

Comment: Use. self instead of ViewController() if loadMyImage(name:String) is in same controller you are calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing *becomes* `nil` in your view controller, because you're not using your view controller, but a brand new instance of your view controller class. Here

```
ViewController().loadMyImage(name: name)
```

you create a new instance and call `loadMyImage` on it. That new instance you're creating is not related to currently displaying view controller, is not on navigation stack, and it exists only within the scope of your `if {}` and will be deallocated immediately.

I assume this code

```
let playbackPoint = defaults.float(forKey: "pbpoint")
if eachTime > Double(playbackPoint) {
   let name = imageList[timeList.index(of: eachTime)!]
   ViewController().loadMyImage(name: name)
}
```

resides within your view controller? If so, do:

```
let playbackPoint = defaults.float(forKey: "pbpoint")
if eachTime > Double(playbackPoint) {
   let name = imageList[timeList.index(of: eachTime)!]
   self.loadMyImage(name: name)
}
```

Otherwise (this is not called in your view controller), you need to pass your view controller instance to this function.

Comment: Oh oops forgot about that! Thanks a lot!